# Reoccurring Coroutine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I'm trying to figure out a clean way to have a method which loops through a recurring coroutine and then terminates when the coroutine is successful, if not it re-invokes itself and yields double the amount of seconds.

```
public IEnumerator ReoccurringCoroutine(IEnumerator coroutineToRun)
{
    int timeToWait = 1;

    bool isSuccessful = false;

    while(!isSuccessful)
    {
        StartCoroutine(coroutineToRun(taskSuccessful =>
        {
            isSuccessful = taskSuccessful;
        }));

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeToWait);

        timeToWait *= 2;
    }
}
```

I have the code above, but I can't work out how to re-run itself, can I just call RecoccuringCoroutine() in the callback of coroutineToRun, or is that super messy? There must be a much cleaner way of doing this. Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public IEnumerator ReoccurringCoroutine(IEnumerator coroutineToRun)
{
    int timeToWait = 1;

    bool isSuccessful = false;

    while(!isSuccessful)
    {
        yield return StartCoroutine(coroutineToRun(taskSuccessful =>
        {
            isSuccessful = taskSuccessful;
        }));

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeToWait);

        timeToWait *= 2;
    }
}
```

The idea is in the yield return StartCoroutine. ReoccuringCoroutine is pending on coroutineToRun to finish. Once the inner coroutine is done, it will return control to ReoccuringCoroutine.

You are actually doing the same process with WaitForSeconds.